# Is using 2 webservers (static/dynamic) an overkill to the website?

Tags: static, nginx, apache2, webserver

I use 2 webservers:

- A dynamic website that servers static content.
- A static website with content for the first website.
  Technology: apache2/nginx for example...

Is this overkill?
Is this better or worse for the website?

Comment: do you mean running two webserver machines, or having both apache webserver and nginx server processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be advisable to use one webserver:

- Your dynamic webserver can deliver also static content
- This will reduce the complexity of your setup
- This will improve maintenance
- This will improve performance, when everything is on one server

2 webservers should only be used to load-balance, when there is high traffic. This is not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned web-servers are both able to serve static and dynamic content (PHP, FastCGI, ..) at the same time.

Why do you want to run two servers if one can do both? With one you will need less memory and you can have virtual hosts for the same port.

Comment: Is well know that Apache2 would better manage PHP process, right?

Answer (score 0):

Yah just run nginx and php-fpm, nginx can deliver the static content directly without touching a PHP process (unlike Apache2) so it's much more efficient.

Comment: Is well know that Apache2 would better manage PHP process, right? I can use on for PHP and another for static content... thats what I mean

Comment: Yah I do run that setup in certain cases, I run nginx in the front to serve static content and it proxies all requests for php pages to Apache2 at the back. But honestly with PHP 5.3 and php-fpm in the core release - nginx PHP mangement is now more advanced (Self healing/dynamic thread based auto scaling etc).

Answer (score 0):

Companies in general have Apache and that Apache has modules or integrations with systems that are not easy to remove.

It is common to see three layers: NGINX - Apache - Java Server

And every piece serves a different (very important) purpose.